# Fail to try insert data in a one-to-many relationship with additional fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a record from the parent relationship.

My models

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cheque extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "numero",
        "banco",
        "factura_id",
    ];

    public function factura()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Factura');
    }
}

class Factura extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'cliente_id',
        'cotizacion_id',
        'sub_total',
        'porcentaje_descuento',
        'descuento_total',
        'total',
        'iva',
    ];

 public function cheque()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Cheque');
    }
```

This is my code in FacturaController

```php
$factura = Factura::create($request->all());

$factura->cheque()->create($request->cheque);
```

The request:

```php
{
    "cliente_id" : "3",
    "nombre" : "gustavo",
    "sub_total" : 20000.50,
    "porcentaje_descuento" : 20,
    "descuento_total" : 50,
    "total" : 100,
    "iva" : 12,
    "cheque" : {
                    "1" : {
                            "numero" : "25525886",
                            "banco" : "banesco"
                          }
                }     
}
```

The 'cheque' is created but the fields 'numero' and 'banco' are left blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$request->cheque[1]`.

Comment: This works fine. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$factura->cheque($factura_id)->create($request->cheque);`

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $factura = Factura::create($request->all());
$cheque = Cheque::create($request->only(['input', 'inputenter code here']);
$cheque = factura_id = $factura-id;
$cheque->save();
```

it's something like this